# Error: Appium session has been terminated

Tags: selenium

I have started session on Appium, the iOS simulator loads; then the appium inspector gets launched
Now, I run my selenium code in eclipse, it runs successfully. But when I try to inspect an element using the appium inspector, the session ends.
Also, I did add 'newCommandTimeout', but it didn't work.

This is the message I get: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncrwq.png)**Error: Session has been terminated**

Below is the log: -

```
[2017-07-19 09:04:23][Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.6.5
[2017-07-19 09:04:23][Appium] Non-default server args:
[2017-07-19 09:04:23][Appium]   address: 127.0.0.1
[2017-07-19 09:04:23][Appium]   logTimestamp: true
[2017-07-19 09:04:23][Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 127.0.0.1:4723


[2017-07-19 09:05:12][HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/4ad54d66-8e97-450f-82a7-333c65826a7b/title 200 11 ms - 83 
[2017-07-19 09:05:12][RemoteDebugger] Checking document readyState
[2017-07-19 09:05:12][RemoteDebugger] Sending javascript command (function (){ return document.readyState; })()
[2017-07-19 09:05:12][RemoteDebugger] Sending '_rpc_forwardSocketData:' message to remote debugger
[2017-07-19 09:05:12][RemoteDebugger] Received applicationSentData response
[2017-07-19 09:05:12][RemoteDebugger] Found data handler for response
[2017-07-19 09:05:12][RemoteDebugger] Received data response from socket send: 'complete'
[2017-07-19 09:05:12][RemoteDebugger] Original command: sendJSCommand
[2017-07-19 09:05:12][RemoteDebugger] readyState was "complete"
[2017-07-19 09:05:12][RemoteDebugger] Page is ready
[2017-07-19 09:05:12][iOS] New page listing is same as old, doing nothing
[2017-07-19 09:05:17][HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/532e6a91-c837-4bf5-acd1-08ba09d69988/source {}
[2017-07-19 09:05:17][MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.getPageSource() with args: ["532e6a91-c837-4bf5-acd1-08ba09d69988"]
[2017-07-19 09:05:17][XCUITest] Executing command 'getPageSource'
[2017-07-19 09:05:17][JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /source] to [GET http://localhost:8100/session/45EB1D20-3547-4558-84E6-EC5441211AFA/source] with no body
[2017-07-19 09:05:17][JSONWP Proxy] Got response with status 200: "{\n  \"value\" : \"Session does not exist\",\n  \"sessionId\" : \"67D07A1C-FC76-4A17-ABEF-F428BFEF207A\",\n  \"status\" : 6\n}"
[2017-07-19 09:05:17][HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/532e6a91-c837-4bf5-acd1-08ba09d69988/source 404 7 ms - 108
```

**Below is my selenium code:**

```
package com.mobile.automation;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;

public class iossample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {

        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Safari");
        cap.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
        cap.setCapability("platformVersion", "10.3");
        cap.setCapability("deviceName", "iPhone 6s");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, "300000");

        URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");
        Thread.sleep(5000);

        IOSDriver<WebElement> driver = new IOSDriver<>(url, cap);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.get("https://facebook.com/");
        System.out.println("Page title is: " +driver.getTitle());

    }

}
```

Comment: I notice on your log that the current sessionId is different from the one in your request. A possible scenario would be that your previous session is still running. Try to quit the session before starting a new one and see if that solves it.